# Google PubSub - Counting messages in push subscription with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

On GCP I am trying to calculate how many messages are queued/waiting to be acknowledged in a push subscription, with NodeJS.

I am using the @google-cloud/monitoring package though cannot see any example in the documentation for retrieving Google PubSub data.

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/monitoring/latest